# How to iterate through all elements in an SVG without losing structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I built a tool that loads user generated SVG's to edit. But since it's user generated content, I'd like to loop through all elements in the SVG (loaded using the load() function of Snap) before appending it to the editor to set fill colors and remove unwanted elements.

The code I now have works fine as for the normalizing part, but it flattens the whole SVG hierarchy:

```
var allNodes = source.selectAll('*:not(svg):not(defs):not(desc):not(title)');
allNodes.forEach(function(subelement) {
    // loop through all elements
    logocreator.normalizeSvgElement(subelement, viewBox);
});
return allNodes;
```

Some of the SVG's rely on the hierarchy in the SVG file. For example, one SVG contained multiple icons (paths) in groups and all of them, except one, had a `style="display: none"`. When flattening the elements in the SVG all paths were shown and a big mess was the result.

So, what I need is a way to loop through all elements in the source of a SVG and normalize each individual element, before adding the contents to my own SVG (the editor).

Comment: Why don't you also append the hidden svg nodes into your editor ? What is the exact purpose of your normalization ?

Comment: The SVGs often are built with use of a template which has instructions/elements outside te viewbox. Icon publishers are supposed to remove them before saving the final icon, but apparantly they often forget this. So I have to parse the SVG's that are being loaded and remove all elements outside of the viewbox, elements that are hidden (to keep things clean) and I have to remove unwanted fills and other attributes to make sure all icons are looking the same.

Comment: That will be tricky : it's possible to have svg elements inside svg. You are removing all of them... Some shapes are only visible thanks to the elements they refer in the `<defs>` element, you remove those... There are three ways to declare the fill color of an element... For your issue, you'd have to iterate through each node, try to see if when you remove a maybe-unwanted-one it does affect any of the wanted-ones... Kinda hard. But since it seems your resulted svg files won't have animations nor scripts in them, I think the best for you is to only do this sanitizing when you do the export.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.. in the example above I create an array of all elements and after looping through this array I return the array to the icon loading method.

I changed the function to return the `source` variable which has been altered in the normalization-function. All elements get marked or altered in this function and before returning the resultset I remove all elements marked for deletion:

```
var allNodes = source.selectAll('*');
allNodes.forEach(function(subelement) {
    logocreator.normalizeSvgElement(subelement, viewBox);
});
source.selectAll('[data-removeme="true"]').remove();
return source.selectAll('svg > *');
```